# Bootstrap, как расположить часть элементов navbar справа?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В мобильной версии иконка меню находится справа, а в десктопной - вот так, слева:

[image: десктоп версия]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sushi</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Судя по всему на маленьких разрешениях у вас убирается класс `.pull-right` отмените это действие и список будет находиться всегда справа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы поставили пункты меню внутрь блока `.navbar-header`. Этот блок на мобильных устройствах растягивается на всю ширину экрана, а на десктопе сжимается влево.

Перекройте ему свойство `float`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

А на мобильном экране этому блоку не нужен `margin-right`. Это свойство бутстрап определяет через `.container-fluid > .navbar-header`, поэтому и перебивать нужно через него же:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Для других размеров экрана такие же свойства прописывает сам бутстрап. А если бы не прописывал — мы бы заставили. Поэтому упростим:

```
.container-fluid > .navbar-header {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

И не забудьте подключить джиквери и скрипты бутстрапа, что меню разворачивалось пр нажатии на кнопку.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container-fluid > .navbar-header {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sushi</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```